# .htaccess rule for getting requested file size

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wonder if there can be such a thing. I wanna check for size of the file and then do htaccess rules based on it. For example:

```
# like this line
CheckIf {REQUESTED_FILE_SIZE} 50 # MB
AuthName "Login title"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

It's clear that I want to make some files with specific file size available to some users only (Using Authentication)

Any idea is appreciated.

**Update #1**

*should be done in htaccess*

**Update #2**

*There are so many files and their URLs are already posted in blog. So can't separate larger files to another folder and update each post, also the limitation of file size may change in future.*

**Update #3**

*It's a windows server with PHP & helicon App installed*

**Update #4**

Some people got confused about the real issue and I didn't clear it as well either.

.htaccess **+** PHP file for authentication (uses API) and checking file size **+** All downloadable files are all in the same server **BUT** our website is hosted on a different server.

Comment: This is only possible using another script that can be used in `.htaccess`. There is no server variable to determine the file size.  Your only other recourse is to deal with this from a front-end proxy.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid you mean checking file size like within php?

Comment: yes, something like that or use a reverse proxy like nginx and have it handle this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*At the time I asked the question Apache 2.4 was out so this answer could be right.*

**Apache Expressions**

As of Apache 2.4 a new capability called [Expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) were introduced. According to this, you can use some functions within your directives and also in conjunction with `RewriteCond`.

Fortunately there is a function named `filesize()` which is able to compare a file size along with *Comparison operators:* **-et -gt -ge -lt -le -ne**

Saying that - however documentation lacks information regarding to this function - below is corresponding rules for comparing a file size:

```
RewriteCond expr "filesize('%{REQUEST_FILENAME}') -gt 52428800"
RewriteRule ** **
```

Using Expressions inside `RewriteCond` should be done within this syntax:

```
RewriteCond expr "..."
```

**BNF**:

```
expr        ::= "true" | "false"
              | "!" expr
              | expr "&&" expr
              | expr "||" expr
              | "(" expr ")"
              | comp
```

You can find complete [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) at documentation page.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously .htaccess cannot check the requested file size and act accordingly. What you can possibly do is to make use of [**`External Rewriting Program feature of RewriteMap`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg)

You need to define a `RewriteMap` like this your Apache config first:

```
RewriteMap checkFileSize prg:/home/revo/checkFileSize.php
```

Then inside your .htaccess define a rule like this by passing :

```
RewriteRule - ${checkFileSize:%{REQUEST_FILENAME}}
```

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is passed to PHP script on STDIN.

Then inside `/home/revo/checkFileSize.php` you can put PHP code to check for size of file and act accordingly like **redirect to a URI that shows basic auth dialog.**

Comment: What's the different of this your `RewriteRule` with `RewriteRule (.*) /path/to/php/checkFileSize.php?URI=$1` then?

Comment: I think both of them will behave same. Personally I have always used `RewriteRule ^ /some/target` type of rules which is also same.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it in 2 steps:

1: htaccess redirecting all requests to one php script, say you have your files inside `/test/` and you wanna make it all handled by `/test/index.php`, eg:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)? /test/index.php?file=$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` is just to avoid loop requests.

2: the `index.php` script does all the auth logic, based on the requested file size, like this:

```
define('LIMIT_FILESIZE',50*1024*1024); // eg.50Mb
define('AUTH_USER', 'myuser');         // change it to your likes
define('AUTH_PW','mypassword');        // change it to your likes

if( filesize($_GET['file'])>LIMIT_FILESIZE ){
  if( !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Canceled';
    exit;
  } 
  else if( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']!=AUTH_USER &&
           $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']!=AUTH_PW ) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Wrong credentials';
    exit;
  }
}

// If we're here, it's fine (filesize is below or user is authenticated)
// offer file for download
$file = rawurldecode($_GET['file']);
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file( $finfo, $file );
header("Content-type: ".$mime );
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
include( $file );
```

There are many possible improvements to it, but it should work as a basis.

Comment: Thanks Paolo but this is done already. When it comes to speed and performance PHP fails in this case. Files are not stored in the same server so we need to get a response from another host to check if usernames and passwords are valid and that takes much time, in addition, handling download resumes will need PHP which is not proper and will have reduction in download speed against normal downloading. Also by this way, beginning of each request for getting a file takes up to 40s (Auth) in our case, so I found it better to handle it with htaccess and htpasswd to answer all of this issues.

Comment: Files are not in the same server? So for each request you would require Apache to get over a network to check the requested file size? I think this would be a serious performance issue too.

Comment: I meant files host are separate from where website itself is. we have files in a dedicated server and website in another host. so if we want go through PHP we should make an API that checks user validation on every download request which we don't want.

Answer (score 2):

I think both answers from @Paolo Stefan and @anubhava are valid (+1).

Note that using RewriteMap will enforce a modification on the apache configuration, not just on the .htaccess file. If you think a little about performance you should, in fact, put all the things you have in .htaccess files into `<directory /same/filesystem/path/as/the/.htaccess/file/>` directives and put an `AllowOverride None` in the VirtualHost configuration. You will certainly gain some speed by avoiding File I/O and dynamic check-for-configuration-files settings for apache for each query (.htaccess files are bad, really). So the fact that **RewriteMap** is not available in .htaccess should not be a problem.

Theses two answers provides a way to dinamically alter the Authentification headers based on the filesize. Now, one important fact you forgot to mention on your question is that the files are not directly available on the same server than the PHP ones and also that you do not want to launch a script on each download.

With current @anubhava solution you would have a call on the OS for file size at each access, and of course this script should be run on the file storage server.

One solution could be to store somewhere (a dedicated database or key value storage?) a file-size index. You could feed this index after each download, you could manage some asynchronous tasks to maintain it. Then on the file storage servers's apache configuration you will have to launch a script checking for file sizes. Using RewriteMap you have several options:

- use a very fast [script](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg) with `prg:` keyword (written in C, Perl, anything, you are not tied to PHP), requesting for this index of file size in this data storage, or even `fastdbd:` to directly execute the SQL query in apache. But this means a query at each request, so you have others solutions.
- [use directly o mapping file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) with `txt:` keyword, having for each filename the matching size already computed, no more queries, just
- even better, use an [hashmap of this file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm) with dbm:` keyword.

With the last two options the file size index is the text file or hashed version of this text file. Apache is caching the hashmap and recompute the cache on restart **or** when the **modification time** of the file is altered. So you would just need to recompute this hashmap after each download to obtain a very fast filesize check in a RewriteRule as shown by anubhava but using

```
RewriteMap checkFileSize dbm:/path/to/filesize_precomputed_index.map
```

You could also try to use [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) on the file servers and check the `Content-Length` header to add the HTTP Auth. Check [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mod-security.user/4229) for a beginning of answer on that subject. But mod_security configuration is not an easy task.

Comment: but using rewritemap in my opinion won't different from using rewriterule as I commented on anubhava answer and if that's true it can't help me

Comment: A rewriteMap can give you a tool which may be fast or slow that you can use in a rewriteRule, and using PHP or something elese on the file server does not mean you use the same PHP as the one used on the web application server. And the rewriteMap could avoid using scripts if it use an hashmap source.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but with a little modification on the file system side you can do it.

If this is a system where users are *uploading* as well as downloading, you can key off of the `Content-Length` header in `mod_rewrite` to put the larger files into a separate directory. (or if you can in some other way move them either way on upload)

Next, in the directory with the larger files you set it to require auth for all files.

Finally use the existence tests in mod_rewrite to transparently redirect the user to the large_files directory if the file is there.

If you can't move the files, you could use symlinks to setup the two layouts.

Comment: Well good luck then. Note that my suggestion explicitly wouldn't require updating the blog entries - the point is although the files are located elsewhere, you use mod_rewrite's conditional file tests so the urls remain the same.

Fairly trivial to setup the two trees using symlinks + find under linux, but I'm afraid I don't know enough powershell to provide a windows version.

Answer (score 1):

According to [*this*](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/200711.mbox/%3C47387C73.9090801@webkist.com%3E) `mod_rewrite` supports a `"-s"` *CondPattern* which checks if the specified *TestString* is a regular file with non-zero size. The attached [patch](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43845) expands the `"-s"` option to support comparisons against arbitrary sizes.

So the questioned:

```
CheckIf {REQUESTED_FILE_SIZE} 50 # MB
```

should work with this *.htaccess* code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s=52428800
```

Comment: Yes but this attachment never patched!

Comment: I used your given clue to answer this question. Thanks

Comment: You're most welcome. I've changed also the 50MB size follow to yours.